# Am I correct with those questions?

Tags: prepositions, difference, articles

Can you help me with those questions, I would like to know what is the best way to ask someone:

> How long have you been working for Apple?

I am not sure I have to use "for" or "At" Apple. And if the person is not working anymore I think the right questions is:

> How long did you work for Apple?

Is that correct?

---

Also:

> I am at ***a*** restaurant

vs

> I am at ***the*** restaurant.

Is there any differences between those two?

Comment: You seem to have some typos in your second pair of examples. Apart from that, you're only supposed to ***ask about one thing in one question*** here on ELL. Are you asking about *[to work] **at/for** [company]*, or *[to be at] **a/the** [location]?*

Comment: I think this should really be split into two questions, since one is about **at** vs. **for**, and one is about the indefinite or the indefinite article.

Comment: The first "subquestion" is a duplicate of [Working in / for / at?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/working-in-for-at), and the second is a duplicate of [(at/in/on) (-/a/the) restaurant](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19689/at-in-on-a-the-restaurant). This is the kind of problem we get with posts containing multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

> How long **have** you **been working** for Apple?

is the correct question for someone still working at Apple.

> How long **did** you work for Apple?

is the correct question for someone who once worked at Apple, but is no longer there.

In your questions about Apple, either **at** or **for** would be correct and would be understood to have the same meaning.

> I'm at **a** restaurant

could be used to tell someone you are *currently* at a restaurant, the restaurant could be any restaurant.

> I'm at **the** restaurant

could be used to tell someone you are at a restaurant which you both already know about, maybe you agreed to meet there.

Answer (score -1):

1. I would use "at" when talking about a big company, such as Apple. "For" is *generally*  used when referring to a person or group of people, not an entity. For example "I work *for* Matthew".
2. There's a typo in your second choice, but if you're asking what the difference is between "a" and "the", it is that "the", which is called a definite article, refers to a specific noun, whereas "a", called an indefinite article, is non-specific.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I can see why this was downvoted. While it's true that we wouldn't use "at" in the case of a boss (in other words, it's "I work _for_ Matthew," not, "I work _at_ Matthew") the inverse is not necessarily true. In fact, [these Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worked+at+IBM%2Cworked+for+IBM%2Cworked+at+General+Electric%2Cworked+for+General+Electric&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) show that, when talking about a big company, using _for_ may be **more** widespread than using  _at_.

Comment: Understood. That's kind of what I was trying to say by writing "*generally*", that it's not a set in stone rule, but I take your point. Thanks for the feedback.